No module named 'selenium.webdriver.remote'
Установил селениум, после установки запустил код:
from selenium import webdriver
Выдает ошибку:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.remote'
Установил селениум c помощью pip install selenium, в терминале при вызове pip list версия селениума почему- то None
